# Is there a way to solve __enter__ AttributeError in ContextDecorator?

Tags: python-3.x, contextmanager

I'm trying to create a ContextDecorator. Here's my code:

```py
class CmTag(ContextDecorator):

    def __init__(self, cm_tag_func):
        self.cm_tag_func = cm_tag_func
        
    def __enter__(self):        
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        if exc_type is not None:
            traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
        else:
            name = self.cm_tag_func.__name__
            print(name)

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):

        name = self.cm_tag_func.__name__
        print(name)
        print(kwargs)
        self.cm_tag_func(**kwargs)

@CmTag
def testing(**kwargs):
    pass

with testing(foo='bar') as t:
    print('a test')
```

I expect the output to be:

```
testing
{'foo':'bar'}
a test
testing
```

That is, it first prints the name of the function. Then it prints out `kwargs` as a dictionary.
Then it prints out whatever is there inside the context manager, which is 'a test', in this case. Finally upon exit, it prints out the name of the function again.

Instead, it says:

```
testing
{'foo': 'bar'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/sierra/src/sierra/test.py", line 32, in <module>
    with testing(foo='bar') as t:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I saw other solutions saying `__enter__` was not defined. But I've done it here.

How do I rectify this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```py
with testing(foo='bar') as t:
    print('a test')
```

since `testing` is an object of `CmTag`, you perform a call to `__call__`, however, you return `None` in that method instead of returning `self`.
Adding `return self` at the end of that method would fix it.